# GenInvokeEnumStackProviders failed

Tags: windbg, dump

Today I wanted to write a crash dump and I got the error message

```
0:000> .dump /ma c:\classid_loads_net4.dmp
Creating c:\classid_loads_net4.dmp - mini user dump
GenInvokeEnumStackProviders(C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\mscordacwks.dll) failed, 0x8007007f
Dump successfully written
```

I googled for `GenInvokeEnumStackProviders` but there are no results at all.

What could the reason for this error message be and what impact could this have on the dump (which was successful according the last message)?

Using WinDbg 6.3.9600

### Update 2014-09-18

Same error again today, reproducible at the moment. In Process Monitor I can see that WinDbg tries to access verifier.dll while writing the dump

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Debuggers\x86\verifier.dll
```

However, the file does not exist in that place. From the list of loaded modules I see it is loaded from

```
0:008> lm fm verifier
start    end        module name
6ddf0000 6de50000   verifier C:\Windows\syswow64\verifier.dll
```

In addition (not sure it is related) I get errors dumping the .NET heap:

```
0:008> !dumpheap -stat
c0000005 Exception in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\sos.dumpheap debugger extension.
      PC: 6b55dbe8  VA: 00000000  R/W: 0  Parameter: 00000000
```

Still using WinDbg 6.3.9600

The problem persists, even after a reboot and after disabling application verifier.

Comment: FYI: Does not occur in WinDbg 6.2.9200